# TypeError at /registration __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

`__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument `'null'`

> Exception Location:
>     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py in
>   **init**, line 196 Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python Python Version:     2.7.2 Python Path:
>
> ['/home/forent/myprograms/mysite7', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', 
>   '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
>
> Server time:  Fri, 27 Jan 2012 11:11:22 -0600

#

```
view

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from registration.models import UserDetails
from forms import UserForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def user_details(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        uform=UserForm(request.POST)
        if uform.is_valid():
            profile=uform.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
        else:
            uform=UserForm()
        return render_to_response('career.html',{'uform':uform},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#model

from django.db import models

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fname
        return self.lname
        return self.email
        return self.address
        return self.country
#forms

from django import forms
from registration.models import UserDetails


class UserForm(forms.Form ):
    fname=forms.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
    lname=forms.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)

#urls

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.user_details', name='user_details'),
    # url(r'^mysite7/', include('mysite7.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

#template 

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ uform.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" ....>
</form>
```

this is the code i have writen..

Answer (score 12):

Form fields don't have `null` or `blank` arguments. Those are for model fields only. For form fields, you just have `required`.

However, you should really be using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/) which will create the form fields for you from the model, and allow you to save it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Not positive, but I don't think you can use `null=True` or `blank=True` on a `forms.CharField()`, you are passing null as a parameter to the init() of the `forms.CharField` and the interpreter is throwing this error. Try removing `null=True` from:

Change your forms to:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form ):
fname=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
lname=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
email = forms.EmailField()
address = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
country = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Per the django site [Django Form Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/), CharField has two optional arguments for validation: max_length and min_length, along with required.