# AttributeError at /registration/ 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'UserForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Exception Location:     /home/forent/myprograms/mysite7/registration/views.py in user_details, line 15
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:    

['/home/forent/myprograms/mysite7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Mon, 30 Jan 2012 03:24:22 -0600
```

i got the error like this . i cant save my form. please help me to save my form

my codes are as follows

```
#view 

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from registration.models import UserDetails
from forms import UserForm
from django import forms
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def user_details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanx/')

    else:
        form = UserForm()        
    return render_to_response("career.html", {"form": form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


#form 

    from django import forms
from registration.models import UserDetails


class UserForm(forms.Form ):
    fname=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

#model 

from django.db import models

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fname
        return self.lname
        return self.email
        return self.address
        return self.country


#url

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.user_details', name='user_details'),
    # url(r'^mysite7/', include('mysite7.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

# template 

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" ....>
</form>
```

i also wish to add the ajaxcode with my code for disply the first 3 fileds of form in one page . and next page for remaining 2 fields . and the pages want to disply in singl window.  and also have to validate the fields . but i dont have the clear idea about the ajax with django . how can i apply all these things in my code

Answer (score 4):

You can't save a form. A form is used to display data from your models (DB) to the user (usually). You can save an instance of a model *from* a form using `forms.ModelForm`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
```

p.s. Django already has authentication built in, so there is no need to duplicate the code. Have a look at `django.contrib.auth` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: problem solved . saved my form thank you so much...  and can i add the ajax with my code..?

Comment: that's a different issue so you need to open a different question with a better explanation of the problem

Answer (score 1):

The UserForm you have defined is not a ModelForm and therefore [does not have a save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) e.g.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
```

Comment: also, it seems like you have already asked a question related to this question which also suggests ModelForm - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9038546/188955

Answer (score 0):

I encountered `'UserForm' object has no attribute 'save'` error in Django 3 (May 2020). It was because in my forms, I gave only `forms.Form`.

I corrected it by this way:

```
class my_form_name(forms.Form,forms.ModelForm)
```

Note: Meta class is important.